# Trying to make text appear while user input password android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I want a textview to appear when the user types in keys and this is my code

```
TextView mustContain, minChar, alphaNumeric;
```

these are 3 different `TextViews` that have to appear based on certain conditions.

`minChar` should appear as long as the user has typed **less than 8** characters,
`mustContain` should appear if the user types a password **without upper-case or lower case** characters
`alphaNumeric` should appear as long as the user has not typed at least one number

```
 public class AccountDetails extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher

     @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {

            final String validatePassword = password.getText().toString();

            if (validatePassword.length()<8 || validatePassword.length()>24){
                minChar.setText("minimum 8 characters, up to 24 characters");
                minChar.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt("#ff0000"));
            } else if (validatePassword.contains("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z]).{8,}$")){

                mustContain.setText("at least one upper-case and lower-case");
                mustContain.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt("#ff0000"));

            } else if (validatePassword.contains("(?=.*?[0-9])")){

                alphaNumeric.setText("contain alphanumeric");
                alphaNumeric.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt("#ff0000"));
            } else {
                minChar.setText("");
                mustContain.setText("");
                alphaNumeric.setText("");
            }

        }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        final String validatePassword = password.getText().toString();

        if (validatePassword.length()<8 || validatePassword.length()>24){
            minChar.setText("minimum 8 characters, up to 24 characters");
            minChar.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt("#ff0000"));
        } else if (validatePassword.contains("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z]).{8,}$")){


            mustContain.setText("at least one upper-case and lower-case");
            mustContain.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt("#ff0000"));

        } else if (validatePassword.contains("(?=.*?[0-9])")){

            alphaNumeric.setText("contain alphanumeric");
            alphaNumeric.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt("#ff0000"));
        } else {
            minChar.setText("");
            mustContain.setText("");
            alphaNumeric.setText("");
        }
    }


    }
```

Comment: Depending on your design, you might want to look at `TextInputLayout` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the setVisibility() function. Initialize your textViews visibility fo false and when the codition is fulfilled set the visibility to true. For example:

```
minChar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
if (validatePassword.length()<8 || validatePassword.length()>24){
            minChar.setText("minimum 8 characters, up to 24 characters");
            minChar.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt("#ff0000"));
            minChar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea set view invisible. But it doesn't work here I don't know  why. I wonder if I made a mistake somewhere here.